# Compare two xml files, update/merge and save - php simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to use simplexml to compare and complement one xml file with items from the other. Since I'm a novice I tried to find a fitting example for this issue, but days of searching amounted to nearly nothing: only bits and pieces. This first draft isn't much but I hope someone can give me some pointers.

Source xml file: catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
  <item>
    <name>King of Hearts</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>      
    <class>Hearts</class>
    <filter>King</filter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Ace of Spades</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>
    <class>Spades</class>
    <filter>Ace</filter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Eight of Diamonds</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>  
    <class>Diamonds</class>
    <filter>Eight</filter>
  </item>
</catalog>
```

Target xml file: user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
  <item>
    <name>Ace of Spades</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>
    <class>Spades</class>
    <filter>Ace</filter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Knight of Clubs</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>  
    <class>Clubs</class>
    <filter>Knight</filter>
  </item>
</catalog>
```

Updated user file after compare/merge: user-updated.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
  <item>
    <name>Ace of Spades</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>
    <class>Spades</class>
    <filter>Ace</filter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Knight of Clubs</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>
    <class>Clubs</class>
    <filter>Knight</filter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>King of Hearts</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>
    <class>Hearts</class>
    <filter>King</filter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Eight of Diamonds</name>
    <category>playing cards</category>
    <class>Diamonds</class>
    <filter>Eight</filter>
  </item>
</catalog>
```

Php code: merge.php

```
<?php

// catalog.xml in this example contains two extra items as user.xml
// these 'excess items' need to bee updated/copied from catalog.xml to user.xml
// the final order of items in user-updated.xml is of no concern: 
// so it's probably easiest to just add them after the last existing item?

// 1. load data from catalog.xml & user.xml (which have the same root & structure)

$catalog = 'catalog.xml';
$user = 'user.xml';

$sourcexml = simplexml_load_file($catalog);
$targetxml = simplexml_load_file($user);

// 2. compare data and return nodes missing in user.xml

$result = array_diff($targetxml, $sourcexml);

// 3. add missing items (including children) to $targetxml

foreach($result->item as $item) {
    $xml = $targetxml->addChild($item);
    $xml->addChild('name', $item->name);
    $xml->addChild('category', $item->category);
    $xml->addChild('class', $item->class);
    $xml->addChild('filter', $item->filter);        
}

// 4. save updated $targetxml to user.xml

$targetxml->asXML('user-updated.xml');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the best code for you. You can combine 2 or more xml files.

```
<?php

$files = array('catalog.xml', 'user.xml');
$xml = combine_xmls($files);

echo $xml->asXML();


function combine_xmls($files, $key='name'){

    foreach ($files as $file){
        $a = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_file($file)),true);
        $b[] = $a['item'];
    }

    $b = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $b);
    foreach($b as $a) $items[$a[$key]] = $a;

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><catalog></catalog>');

    foreach ($items as $item ){
        $node = $xml->addChild('item');
        foreach ($item as $key=>$val) $node->addChild($key, $val);
    }

    return $xml;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code for your problem. You can use it without problems. :)

```
<?php

$catalog = 'catalog.xml';
$user = 'user.xml';

$sourcexml = simplexml_load_file($catalog);
$targetxml = simplexml_load_file($user);

$a1 = json_decode(json_encode($sourcexml),true);
$a2 = json_decode(json_encode($targetxml),true);

$items = array_map('unserialize', 
    array_unique(
        array_map('serialize', 
            array_merge_recursive($a1['item'], $a2['item'])
        )
    )
);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog></catalog>');

foreach ($items as $item){
    $node = $xml->addChild('item');
    $node->addChild('name', $item['name']);
    $node->addChild('category', $item['category']);
    $node->addChild('class', $item['class']);
    $node->addChild('filter', $item['filter']);     
}

echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

Comment: You're right. This does precisely what I hoped for: when the php script is run, user.xml is updated in relation to catalog.xml whithout deleting or doubling existing items in user.xml. I changed the last line so the output gets saved to user.xml.: $xml->asXML('user.xml');

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this first post/question: what do I do next? Add [solved] to the title? Or give you credits (if I can)...

Comment: Wait, there is one small (I think) problem. Items with the same <name> but different <category> <class> or <filter> do get copied. I would like the <name> node to function like an 'id' so the result (user.xml) contains only unique names. Is this a matter of adding some code to make the <name> content function as a key of some sort?

Comment: [SOLVED] is enough

Comment: I wrote the new best code for u. Look at the my last answer.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Now that the name is 'key' the script only adds items if they are nonexistent (by name). Not if the other nodes vary. You've really helped me. Didn't expect to get a reply so soon. Thanks --> Also I tried to change the name (add solved) but can't seem to find this option. Do I need to copy the lot in a new post or something?

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".